# How to run API call inside background runnable and receive response to multiples fragment in java?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i want to call api request every x second using Runnable and read live response to multiple fragment on every api call.

i try bellow code but if start runnable from FragmentA then can't get response on FragmentB even if runnable already run api call in background.
when i run `RunnableDemo(mContext, this, JsonRpc.Method.TELL_ACTIVE).run();` in fragmentA and start runnable however can get onDataSuccess in fragmentB.
and if i use `RunnableDemo(mContext, this, JsonRpc.Method.TELL_ACTIVE).run();` in FragmentB  then run two time API call for FragmentA and FragmentB.
so, how can i run api call every x second once and receive response on multiple fragments?

thank you,

1. RunnableDemo.java

```
public class RunnableDemo implements Runnable{
   RunnableDemo.RunnableDemoListener listener;


    public void run() {
        if (myRunnable == null) {
            myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if(shouldRun) {
                        running = true;
                        //do something
                        loop();
                    }
                    myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, updateInterval);
                }
            }, updateInterval);
        }
    }


    private void loop() {
       ...retrofit....
              call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Response<ResponseBody> response)
                {
                     listener.onDataSuccess(response);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Throwable t)
                {
                    listener.onDataError("error");

                }
            });
            
    }
    
    

    public void stop() {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onStopped();
        }
        running = false;
        shouldRun = false;
    }

    public final boolean isRunning() {
        return running;
    }
    public final boolean safeStop() {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onStopped();
            }
            shouldRun = false;
            running = false;
            return true;
    }

    // Listener defined earlier
    public interface RunnableDemoListener {
        public void onDataError(String title);
        public void onDataSuccess(Response<ResponseBody> responseBody);
        public void onStopped();
    }

}
```

2. FragmentA.java

```
public class FargmentA extends Fragment implements RunnableDemo.RunnableDemoListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
           RunnableDemo runnableDemo = new RunnableDemo(mContext, this, JsonRpc.Method.TELL_ACTIVE);
          if(!runnableDemo.isRunning()) {
              runnableDemo.run();
          }
    }
    
    
    

    @Override
    public void onDataError(String title) {
        Log.i("TEST", "TestRunnable  onResponse receive error Files: "+ title);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSuccess(Response<ResponseBody> responseBody) {
        Log.i("TEST", "TestRunnable  onResponse receive success Files: "+ responseBody.code());

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopped() {
        Log.i("TEST", "TestRunnable  onResponse receive onStopped Files: ");

    }
    
}
```

3. FragmentB.java

```
public class FargmentB extends Fragment implements RunnableDemo.RunnableDemoListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
           RunnableDemo runnableDemo = new RunnableDemo(mContext, this, JsonRpc.Method.TELL_ACTIVE);
          if(!runnableDemo.isRunning()) {
              runnableDemo.run();
          }
    }
    
    
    

    @Override
    public void onDataError(String title) {
        Log.i("TEST", "TestRunnable  onResponse receive error Files: "+ title);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSuccess(Response<ResponseBody> responseBody) {
        Log.i("TEST", "TestRunnable  onResponse receive success Files: "+ responseBody.code());

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopped() {
        Log.i("TEST", "TestRunnable  onResponse receive onStopped Files: ");

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Use a `LiveData` in an `Activity` scoped `ViewModel`.

Comment: How to use with Runnable? please, can you give me example?

Comment: If you want to run the `Runnable` only once & use its data in multiple Fragments then you can either declare & run it in the host Activity if both the fragments are hosted by the same Activity & get a reference to the data via `((MainActivity) requireActivity()).responseData` or use a callback from Activity to Fragment or you'll have to persist the data to local storage.

Comment: i want to run Runnable in loop every x second.

Comment: I think you need to implement some observer pattern.  If you are not applying architecture then create a singleton class (Repository) and share it between the differents fragments.  The activity can start the polling each predefined time.  https://www.baeldung.com/java-observer-pattern